# How to find the volume using integrals

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, volume

Find the volume using integrals, that is formed/bounded with lines $y^2 + x - 4 = 0, x = 0$, which rotates around $y-axis$.

I tried to solve it by visualizing the model from top-down view, but that didn't get me anywhere(I wasn't sure how to find it through integrals). How can I find the volume?

[image: Graphed out version of the problem:]

Comment: That graph is not $y^2+x+4=0$, which is how you’ve labeled it on the visual.

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor Sorry, I meant $y^2+x-4=0$

Comment: Use the *disks method* or the *cylindrical shells* method. In this case, the disks will be easier, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Volume of revolution is $$\int_a^b \pi x^2 dy$$
Find the coordinates of intersection of the parabola with the y-axis, these are your $b$ and $a$ values.

Then rewrite the equation of $x$ in terms of $y$, and square the result to get $x^2$ in terms of $y$

Plug the rest into the formula and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you did, right?

$\int_{-2}^{2} \pi(4-y^2)^2dy$

The answer should be $107.233$

Comment: For some reason, I put a negative sign in front of the $4$. Thanks!